# PyQt after override dragEnterEvent and dropEvent cursor donot blinking and change

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, overriding, pyside

1. I write the class for overriding dragEnterEvent and dropEvent methods at the QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit object:

```
class ChangeMethodsDnDTagList(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super().__init__()
        self.obj = obj  # will be type = BeforeQtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit
        self.obj.dragEnterEvent = self.dragEnterEvent
        self.obj.dropEvent = self.dropEvent

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if check_text(event.mimeData().text()):
            if self.obj is not None:
                if self.obj.toPlainText() != '':
                    self.obj.setPlainText(self.obj.toPlainText() + ', ' + event.mimeData().text())
                else:
                    self.obj.setPlainText(event.mimeData().text())
```

2. Use it in Application, for override methods in the existing object:

```
    class Application(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QWidget, QtCore.QEvent):
        def __init__(self):
            ...
            super().__init__()
            ...
            self.setupUi(self)
            ...
            ChangeMethodsDnDTagList(self.in_tags_list)
```

3. Drag and Drop works well but after that, the cursor freezes and does not update (blinking, change position).
4. The minimal reproducible example:
   testform.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'testform.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(502, 271)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(502, 271))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(502, 271))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.in_tags_list = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.in_tags_list.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(5, 5, 481, 201))
        self.in_tags_list.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhLatinOnly|QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
        self.in_tags_list.setPlainText("")
        self.in_tags_list.setObjectName("in_tags_list")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

test.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import testform as design
import re


class Application(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QWidget, QtCore.QEvent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        ChangeMethodsDnDTagList(self.in_tags_list)


class ChangeMethodsDnDTagList(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super().__init__()
        self.obj = obj  # will be type = BeforeQtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit
        self.obj.dragEnterEvent = self.dragEnterEvent
        self.obj.dropEvent = self.dropEvent

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if check_text(event.mimeData().text()):
            if self.obj is not None:
                if self.obj.toPlainText() != '':
                    self.obj.setPlainText(self.obj.toPlainText() + ', ' + event.mimeData().text())
                else:
                    self.obj.setPlainText(event.mimeData().text())


def check_text(text, mask="""^[a-zA-Z0-9_:, \n\t]+$"""):
    """Check input text"""
    match = re.match(mask, text)
    return bool(match)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Application()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc, ready

Comment: By the way, what you're doing is *not* subclassing -I hope you're not thinking it is- and that's not a very elegant way to do method overriding (and I also believe, not very pythonic too).

Comment: @musicamante Can you advise how to improve my code I would be very grateful. 
I'm new at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reimplement `dragMoveEvent` too, it can be identical to `dragEnterEvent` so just add one line similar to the others:

```
class ChangeMethodsDnDTagList(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super().__init__()
        self.obj = obj  # will be type = BeforeQtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit
        self.obj.dragEnterEvent = self.dragEnterEvent
        self.obj.dropEvent = self.dropEvent

        self.obj.dragMoveEvent = self.dragEnterEvent
```

Then include a line in `dropEvent` to move the cursor to the end of the document after the drop.

```
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if check_text(event.mimeData().text()):
            if self.obj is not None:
                if self.obj.toPlainText() != '':
                    self.obj.setPlainText(self.obj.toPlainText() + ', ' + event.mimeData().text())
                else:
                    self.obj.setPlainText(event.mimeData().text())
                    
                self.obj.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
```

Answer (score 1):

While technically the accepted solution correctly addresses the specific matter at hand (the missing `dragMoveEvent` implementation), it still follows the OP approach which I strongly believe being wrong in many aspects.

First of all, the following is *not* subclassing:

```
class ChangeMethodsDnDTagList(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super().__init__()
        self.obj = obj  # will be type = BeforeQtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit
        self.obj.dragEnterEvent = self.dragEnterEvent
        self.obj.dropEvent = self.dropEvent
```

While the class correctly inherits from QPlainTextEdit (so, it "is" subclassed), it actually is *never* used as such, and the following would have worked anyway:

```
class ChangeMethodsDnDTagList:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        # ...
```

As you can see, the above is a standard python object class (it would be `class ChangeMethodsDnDTagList(object):` for Python 2), which is sufficient for what you need.

In fact, you could do the same even without a class:

```
def changeDndMethods(obj):
    # any access to the instance is now done through obj, not self.obj
    def dragEnterEvent(event):
        # ...
    def dropEvent(event):
        # ...
    obj.dragEnterEvent = dragEnterEvent
    obj.dragMoveEvent = dragEnterEvent
    obj.dropEvent = dropEvent
```

While any of the above works, that doesn't provide actual subclassing, as it makes access to instance methods more awkward or difficult.

The problem comes from the fact that you're using a ui built in designer, which already creates the instances of the widgets based on the standard Qt classes. In order use your own subclasses, you need to *promote* widgets.

The procedure is pretty simple, but I suggest you to do some research in order to better understand how it works:

- right click on the widget you want to subclass in the ui you're creating in Designer;
- from the context menu, select "Promote to...";
- ensure that the correct class is selected in the combo "Base class name" (QPlainTextEdit in your case, it should be already selected);
- type the name of subclass you're going to use (eg. `MyCustomPlainText`) in the field "Promoted class name";
- in the field "Header file" type the python file name (without the `.py` extension, eg. "mycustomclasses") in which the subclass is defined;
- click "Add" to create the promoted class and then "Promote" to *actually* promote your widget;
- save and call `pyuic` again;
- in the file "mycustomclasses.py" create the class and appropriately override its methods:

```
class MyCustomPlainText(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
   def dropEvent(self, event):
        if check_text(event.mimeData().text()):
            if self.toPlainText() != '':
                # ...
```

Finally, Qt doesn't play well with multiple inheritance of its own classes, and you're just lucky that the following works:

```
class Application(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow, QtWidgets.QWidget, QtCore.QEvent):
```

QMainWindow already inherits from QWidget, and QEvent shouldn't normally be subclassed at all (and not along with QWidget, in any case), so, the following is sufficient.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        # unnecessary, setupUi already does this
        # self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

Note that I also changed the class name: there already is an "application" class (QApplication), which does *not* what a main *window* does. Remember that while you can name objects as much as you like, naming is *very* important.

Comment: thank you very much for your time, your analysis was very helpful to me.